# Connectedness of $GL_n(\mathbf{R}^{+})

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, connectedness, path-connected

Want to show any two matrices in $GL_n(\mathbf{R})^+$, i.e. $n\times n$ matrices with positive determinant can be connected by a path. Now It being a manifold path connectedness and connectedness are equivalent.

Using Gram-Schmidt we can show that $GL_n(\mathbf{R})^+$ deformation-retracts to $SO(n)$. Now, $SO(2)\cong S^1$, so connected. And $SO(n)/SO(n-1)\cong S^{n-1}$, so using induction I get $SO(n)$ is path connected. Hence $GL_n(\mathbf{R})^+$ is path connected. But it's all abstract, can anyone help with an explicit formula for such a path?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ have QR decompositions $A = Q_1R_1$ and $B = Q_2R_2$, then we can build an explicit path by connecting $Q_1$ to $Q_2$ in $SO(n)$ and $R_1$ to $R_2$ within the set of upper triangular matrices with positive determinant.

Comment: Very nice idea indeed, didn't think of this before.  but can we get a formula for that ? I mean in terms of the two matrices?

Comment: One can connect two orthogonal matrices in $O(n)$ nicely using an eigendecomposition.  For the upper triangular matrices, it suffices to connect every matrix to a diagonal matrix with $\pm 1$ on the diagonal, and then connect the $\pm 1$ matrices within $SO(n)$.